# dish of water vs dish with water

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is it not correct to say "dish with water"? If it's correct, what is the difference in using **"dish of water"** and **"dish with water"**?

Comment: I'm not native, but to me, they look rather similar

Comment: You usually only use "with" if you say "**a dish filled with water**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both phrases are common, but tend to be used in different contexts. For example:

> A Where can I wash my hands?
> B You can wash them in the dish / bowl of water on the kitchen table.

Here somebody merely indicates where the container holding the water can be found. The implication is that it is full or nearly full in the same way as **a bucket of water** suggests a full bucket.

On the other hand people tend to use **with** when they mean **containing**, especially if there is more than one container concerned:

> A Which is the dish with hot water?
> B It's the dish beside the bowl with the red pattern.

There is no suggestion here that the dish is full, merely that it contains hot water. The implication is that there is more than one dish.

You could also ask:

> Where is the dish with hot water.

Again you mean the dish that contains hot water.

The same distinctions would be true if you were talking about a bucket of water or a bucket with water (in it). Ditto for any other container.

These are not grammatical issues. The choice comes down to idiom and context.

Comment: Yes, you are right. )) In my native language it has the same logic. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

They are both grammatically correct, but the phrases mean slightly different things. Also, right up front, neither is a phrase that I, as a native speaker, am familiar with.

A dish **of** water sounds more like it's dedicated for that purpose than a dish **with** water.

Answer (score 0):

Children have sung,

```
Jack and Jill went up the hill to fetch a pail *of* water
Jack fell down and broke his crown and Jill came tumbling after.
```

for centuries. Perhaps Jack and Jill had already filled their pail *with* water when the accident happened: we don't know. The rhyme is reticent about this.

In the UK, dogs are given a *bowl of water*: never a dish. Dishes are for food. Bowls are used for all sorts of things, including food. We used to drink from them. Now goldfish live in them.